# Why does my autofilter filter absolutely every row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have filters applied on row three. Many lines have a zero value, but not all. I want to filter out those zeroes. I expected this code to accomplish that. But instead it hides every row. What's going wrong? How can I filter out the rows that have zero in Column H?

```
Set budgWB = Workbooks.Open(Range("A3").Value & VarCellValue & "\" & VarCellValue & ".xlsm")
Set budgBS = budgWB.Sheets("Budget Spread")

Workbooks(VarCellValue).Activate
budgBS.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
budgBS.Range("25:37,153:165,594:603,715:727,786:798,846:858").EntireRow.Hidden = True
budgBS.Range("H3").AutoFilter _
 Field:=1, _
 Criteria1:=Array("0", "><"), _
 VisibleDropDown:=False
budgBS.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
budgBS.Range("A1").Select
budgWB.Save
budgWB.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... note the criteria correction of `"<>0"`

```
Set budgWB = Workbooks.Open(Range("A3").Value & VarCellValue & "\" & VarCellValue & ".xlsm")
Set budgBS = budgWB.Sheets("Budget Spread")

Workbooks(VarCellValue).Activate
budgBS.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
budgBS.Range("25:37,153:165,594:603,715:727,786:798,846:858").EntireRow.Hidden = True
budgBS.Range("H3").AutoFilter _
 Field:=1, _
 Criteria1:="<>0", _
 VisibleDropDown:=False
budgBS.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
budgBS.Range("A1").Select
budgWB.Save
budgWB.Close
```